# Matlab join elements of matrix

Tags: matlab

I have n x m matrix with binary data, something like this:

```
A=   2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     3     3     3     3
     2     2     2     2
     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1
```

I want to join every *x* element of every row in *A*, to get matrix like:

```
x=2
A= 22   22
   33   33
   00   00
   00   00
   33   33
   22   22
   00   00
   11   11
```

Can you help with that?

Comment: Will `A` always contain 1 length integers? i.e. one of 0123456789 only

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes. It is binary numbers, I change them to make my question more clear

Comment: If it's always 1 digit then multiplying the 1st column (/3rd/5th/...) by 10 and adding the 2nd column (/4th/6th/...) would be much quicker than string operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a string operation. So start by making `A` a matrix of strings

```
B = string(A);
```

Now you can join every `x` element with `join`

```
x = 2;
n = size(A,2)/x;
for i = 1:n
    C(:,i) = join(B(:,(i-1)*x+1:i*x),'',2)
end
```

Finally you can make it numbers again

```
D = double(C);
```

Please note that with this I assume that `x` divides `size(A,2)`.